# What is the effect of this function (function burn)

Tags: solidity

I would like to know what are the effects of this function :

```
    function burn(uint256 _amount) external {
    _burn(msg.sender, _amount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"A burn function is a smart contract function programmed into a cryptocurrency protocol that allows for anyone to carry out a coin burn at any time.

A burn function automatically carries out the process of burning coins and updating the total supply of a coin as long as a person has the number of coins they desire to burn.

When a burn function is executed to burn a coin, it permanently removes those coins from circulation, and the transaction is publicly verifiable on the currency's blockchain. Binance Coin (BNB) initially utilised the burn function when it was on the Ethereum network for carrying out quarterly coin burns."

Basically it destroys any value that is sent to it.

Comment: You meant that anyone is allowed to burn tokens since that is an external function

Comment: Yes anyone can burn a token.

Comment: Everyone is allowed to burn tokens from their own wallet, yeah, since there's no check over who msg.sender is, here